# how to get a sub string from a string separated by commas in C

Tags: c, substring, arrays

I want to get a sub array from a array in the programming language C

for instance if i have a char array:

```
c[]= "Peter,peter911@hotmail.com,213342,IGE

d[]= "JohnSilva,johnsilva@hotmail.com,213342,ETI
```

The thing is, i want a general code where when given an index, an array and a char that separates the index, it will put the following index, from a comma to another comma into a array.Index starts at 0

example : d[], index=1, separator: ','

the result= johnsilva@hotmail.com

```
main(){
    char delimitador;
    char linha[100];
    int index;
    printf("index\n");
    scanf("%d",index);
    printf("char delimitador\n");
    scanf("%c",caractere);
    printf("linha"\n");
    scanf("%c",linha);
    char vector[50];
    int i=0;
    int contador;
    while(i!=index){
        contador++;
        if(c[contador]==delimitador){
            strncpy(vector,linha,contador-1);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't write the code for you. What have you tried?

Comment: Im sorry im new at this :/
main(){

        char delimitador;
        char linha[100];
        int index;

        printf("index\n");
        scanf("%d",index);

        printf("char delimitador\n");
        scanf("%c",caractere);

        printf("linha"\n");
        scanf("%c",linha);
        char vector[50];
        int i=0;
        int contador;
        while(i!=index){
                contador++
                if(c[contador]==delimitador){
                        strncpy(vector,linha,contador-1);
                        i++;
                }
        }

}

Comment: i dont know yet how to work with this sorry :/

Comment: @Joao Silva Rather than comment, update your original post.

Comment: 0) `scanf("%d",index);..scanf("%c",caractere);` --> `scanf("%d", &index);..scanf("%c", &caractere);`

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *get_field(char *out_buff, const char *csv, int index, char separator){
    int i;
    char *p = out_buff;
    for(i=0; i < index && *csv; ++csv){
        if(*csv == separator)
            ++i;//count separator
    }
    if(i == index){
        while( *csv && *csv != separator )
            *p++ = *csv++;//cut out
    }
    *p = '\0';
    return out_buff;
}

int main(void){
    char d[]= "JohnSilva,johnsilva@hotmail.com,213342,ETI";
    char vector[50];
    get_field(vector, d, 1, ',');
    puts(vector);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice +1.  Minor: maybe `i != index` --> `i < index` to better cope with unusual negative `index`.

Comment: sure. I should also take into account that madman want to specify a negative field number. ;-)

Comment: Much code on SO has little problems.  Your code is better.  Your posts employ `size_t`, `const`, and other small details correctly.  I think many people (sane and madman) use your code.  Your code needs to work at a higher standard.  So I suggest these small corner issues for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **strtok** function to tokenize a given string.

for further information please visit given link.
[strtok()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm)

Comment: This is merely a comment. If you have not enough reputation to post comments as a *comment*, rather than as an *answer*, then better not comment at all.

Answer (score 0):

Strtok function could be used . But if you are not familiar with the function a simple char by char read of string could help . Check this : http://wethecomputerguys.com/2014/12/10/break-string-using-index-and-separator/ .. Hope it helps you..

Answer (score 0):

Read about string parsing, and then write a string parsing function that returns everything between the n-th comma and the next comma, then use an array of the form `char *foo[]`.

String parsing: get number of commas, select desired one, get string between the two, make array.